# Is it possible for a GraphQl query to accept some RSQL (or SQL) for narrowing?

Tags: sql, graphql, narrowing, rsql

Recently I've been looking into how to querify data using GraphQL and I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow provide the appropriate parameters to narrow a given Query, something like RSQL snippets ( https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser )? I found for example such a fragment of Query:

```
{
    search(id: "4124", rsql: "type==TTK and direction=="Directional",
type: "Object" ) { 
    id
    ... on Object
       type
       direction
    }
   }   
}
```

So it seems possible to me, although I don't quite understand how it works. Could someone explain how to pass such parameters? I would find it useful in searching for data after narrowing e.g. by type or name. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: yes, it's possible ... just define variable `rsql` as string type - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables - variables are passed to query/mutation resolver, **if resolver can parse it** then it can use it to fetch DB data/construct SQL query